# Restructuring HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I have some HTML that I need to toggle between two structures - one nested, and one un-nested - to make it easier for users to sort page components in a cms.

Here's the before html...

```
<p><a href="#" id="restructure">Toggle Structure</a></p>
<div id="modules">
  <div class="two_column_box">
    <div class="column_left">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column_right">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two_column_box">
    <div class="column_left">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column_right">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

and after html...

```
<p><a href="#" id="restructure">Toggle Structure</a></p>
<div id="modules">
  <div class="column_left">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column_right">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column_left">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column_right">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can strip out the extra divs, no trouble, but putting them back afterwards - I just don't get how to build up html from plain text and existing DOM elements. Here's the code I have so far...

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#restructure').toggle(
      function() {
        alert('removing structure');
        var module_list = $("#modules > div > div");
        $("#modules").html(module_list);
      },
      function() {
        alert('replacing structure');
        var idx = 1;
        var next;
        var structure = $("");
        while((next = $('#modules > div:nth-child(' + idx++ + ')')).length) {
          var element = next.clone();
          if(idx%2==1) {
            $(structure).append('<div class="two_column_box">').append(element);
          } else {
            $(structure).append(element).append('</div>');
          }
        }
        $("#modules").html(structure);
      }
    );
  });
  </script>
```

Any help in getting the second function of the toggle to work (or in a more idiomatic version of the working code) would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [wrapAll](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapAll#html) in your case since your wrapping multiple elements at once into the same element.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#restructure').toggle(
      function() {
        alert('removing structure');
        var module_list = $("#modules > div > div");
        $("#modules").html(module_list);
      },
      function() {
        alert('replacing structure');
        var next;
        while((next = $('#modules > div.column_left:first, #modules > div.column_right:first')).length)
        {
          next.wrapAll('<div class="two_column_box"></div>');
        }
      }
    );
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I really like how concise your code is. I didn't know that you can pass jQuery element list to html method. Working demo for your code:

http://jsbin.com/apake

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#restructure').toggle(
      function() {
        alert('removing structure');
        $("#modules .column_left, #modules .column_right").moveToGrandparent();
        $(".two_column_box").remove(); 
      },
      function() {
        alert('replacing structure');

        var next = $('#modules > .column_left:first, #modules > .column_right:first');
        while (next.length > 0)
        { 
            var wrapper = $("<div />").addClass("two_column_box");
            next.wrapAll(wrapper);
            next = $('#modules > .column_left:first, #modules > .column_right:first');
        }
      }
    );
  });


  (function($) {

    $.fn.moveToGrandparent = function() {
        return $(this).each(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().append($(this));
        });
    };      

  })(jQuery);
```

Although you're removing structure code worked, I re-wrote it to use a plugin.  As for the replacing structure, I'm using the jQuery [`wrapAll`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapAll) method with a loop that gets the first elements until there aren't any elements remaining.

HTH,
Ben

Comment: Thanks Ben; actually I think that gradbot's code is more concise, but I'll purloin your moveToGrandparent plugin for something else I need ! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Once slight addendum to gradbot's suggestion: the point is that the elements will be sorted using UI sortable, so I needed to re-class the items depending on where they were in the list - odd being lefthand side, even being righthand side. There's probably a quicker way to do it but...

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#restructure').toggle(
        function() {
          alert('removing structure');
          var module_list = $("#modules > div > div");
          $("#modules").html(module_list);
        },
        function() {
            alert('replacing structure');
            $('#modules > div').removeClass();
            $("#modules > div:odd").addClass('column_left');
            $("#modules > div:even").addClass('column_right');
            while((next = $('#modules > div.column_left:first, #modules > div.column_right:first')).length) {  
              next.wrapAll('<div class="two_column_box"></div>');
            }
        }
      );
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: This makes sense when the class was removed during the removing structure toggle path.
This might be redundant since it's working fine without the two new lines?

Comment: Sorry Jimmy - perhaps I wasn't being clear: between the restructure link being clicked the first and second time, the user may have REORDERED the divs (using jQuery UI sortable)  - so the classes used to fetch the pairs will be wrong... hence the need to reset them using :odd and "even.

That said, there may be a simpler way.