# Restructuring my HTML based on the width of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, structure

Basically I want my HTML structure to be restructured when window gets smaller than lets say 400px in width.

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="div1"> -- Loads of content here -- </div>
    <div id="div2"> -- Even more content here -- </div>
    <div id="div3"> -- You can't even imagine how much content here -- </div>
</div>
```

Now, after a user resizes his/hers browser below 400px in witdh I some how need to move div3 above div1, so the structure would look like this:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="div3"> -- You can't even imagine how much content here -- </div>        
    <div id="div1"> -- Loads of content here -- </div>
    <div id="div2"> -- Even more content here -- </div>
</div>
```

I already have, by the use of jquery, a function to mesure the width of the window. But how do I accomplish the rest? I have looked a bit at [this sort of similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082283/restructuring-html-using-jquery), which gave me an idea of how I might be able to, but it didn't quiet help me out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tMutA/1/

You should maybe instead define a set of index parameters on different size and then run an sortby instead.

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();

if(screenWidth < 600) {
    $('#div3').prependTo($('#mainContainer'));
}

$(window).resize(function() {
var screenWidth = $(window).width();

if(screenWidth < 600) {
    $('#div3').prependTo($('#mainContainer'));
} else {
    $('#div2').prependTo($('#mainContainer'));
    $('#div1').prependTo($('#mainContainer'));
}

});
```

Comment: Yeah digged around jquery.com some and came to same idea as this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using **[CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/)** to query the screen width, and adjust accordingly.

Not all browsers support it.

**[Another great article.](http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/)**

Comment: +1 for the Media Query reference. But how do I restructure the HTML?

Comment: There's actually no reason to change the HTML structure. The HTML should be structured with important content first, so that it's more accessible. Changing that is (usually) not the best idea. If you CSS it correctly, you should be good with just the CSS and media-queries.